# I'm using C# (Unity) and can't put variables into my vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Full disclosure, I do not know C# at all. I've been coding this just using the internet. I decided to try learning Unity over the summer before I start my first year at university and have been working on walking controls.
I've been trying to make the character turn in the direction they're facing and while I can get them to go forward just fine. If I have them turn though, subsequently after that any attempt to make them go forward (even if I just have them return to a rotation of 0) end up with the error message "rigidbody.force assign attempt for 'Fox' is not valid. Input force is {NaN, 0.000000, NaN}."
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
//private quaternion rotation;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
public Rigidbody rb;
public float moveSpeed = 10f;
public float rotationSpeed = 7f;

public float rotation;


private float xInput;
private float zInput;
private float directionInput;
public GameObject player;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ProcessInputs();
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
    {
        player.transform.Rotate(0f, -(rotationSpeed), 0f, Space.World);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        player.transform.Rotate(0f,  rotationSpeed, 0f, Space.World);
    }
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Movement
    Move();
}

private void ProcessInputs()
{
    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


}

private void Move()
{
    
    //float xMove;
    //float zMove;        

    rotation = player.transform.rotation.y;
    if (rotation == 0)
    {
        float xMove = 0f;
        float zMove = zInput;

        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(xMove, 0f, zMove) * moveSpeed);
    }
    else if (rotation <= 90)
    {
        float zMove = (float)(Math.Sqrt((zInput*zInput) - ((zInput * (1/(Math.Cos(90 - rotation)))) * (zInput * (1/(Math.Cos(90 - rotation))))) ));
        float xMove = (float)(Math.Sqrt((zInput*zInput) - ((zInput * (1/(Math.Sin(90 - rotation)))) * (zInput * (1/(Math.Sin(90 - rotation))))) ));

        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(xMove, 0f, zMove) * moveSpeed);
    }
    
    //Math.Sqrt((zInput*zInput) - ((zInput * (1/(Math.Cos(rotation)))) * (zInput * (1/(Math.Cos(rotation))))) );
    //Math.Sqrt((zInput*zInput) - ((zInput * (1/(Math.Sin(rotation)))) * (zInput * (1/(Math.Sin(rotation))))) );
   //rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 0f, zInput) * moveSpeed);
   //rb.AddForce(new Vector3(xMove, 0f, zMove) * moveSpeed);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problematic code is here:

```
float zMove = (float)(Math.Sqrt((zInput*zInput) - ((zInput * (1/(Math.Cos(90 - rotation)))) * (zInput * (1/(Math.Cos(90 - rotation))))) ));
float xMove = (float)(Math.Sqrt((zInput*zInput) - ((zInput * (1/(Math.Sin(90 - rotation)))) * (zInput * (1/(Math.Sin(90 - rotation))))) ));

rb.AddForce(new Vector3(xMove, 0f, zMove) * moveSpeed);
```

There's no MathJax here (why??) so let me just drop the code for a moment and show you what you're doing:

```
sqrt( z^2 - (z/Cos)*(z/Cos))
```

But you can multiply out the second term:

```
sqrt( z^2 - (z^2/Cos^2))
```

And then you can factor out the `z^2`:

```
sqrt( z^2 * (1 - (1/Cos^2))
```

:EDIT: - Realized a slight issue with my argument here. Sine and cosine can range between -1 and 1, not just 0 and 1, but the rest of the argument still stands - Cosine *squared* or sine *squared* **will** only range 0 to 1, which will give you imaginary numbers.

:Original: (edited)
Now there's the problem. Cosine (or sine, for the other term) can only range between -1 and 1. So when you do something like `Cos^2`, the negative drops out and it can only range between 0 and 1. That means, when you have that term in the denominator, you get that `1/Cos^2` will range from 1 **at the smallest** to Infinity in the divide-by-zero case.

So you wind up with your `(1/Cos^2)` ranging [1 ... INF], and this means that you get two limits on your equation:

```
sqrt( z^2 * (1 - 1))
```

and

```
sqrt( z^2 * (1 - INF))
```

In the former case, you get zero, and in **every other case** you get the square root of a negative number. This gives you the imaginary number, which gets your the error you see:

> rigidbody.force assign attempt for 'Fox' is not valid. Input force is {NaN, 0.000000, NaN}

because sqrt(-1) is Not a Number (NaN).

It looks like your trying to rotate the force to coincide with the forward and right directions, but you have unit vectors already pointing in those directions, `transform.forward` for z and `transform.right` for x, so just scale those by your `moveSpeed`, add them together, and add that force.

```
Vector3 zMove = rb.transform.forward * moveSpeed;
Vector3 xMove = rb.transform.right * moveSpeed;
rb.AddForce(zMove+xMove);
```

I'll caution you though that you're adding a FORCE here, not setting a speed, so this might not get you what you're after. I say that because the variable name in your code is `moveSpeed`. You might be happier setting

```
rb.velocity = zMove + xMove;
```

but it's your game and you can experiment with what you want :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to C# so I don't understand it. I forgot to use radiens so that seems to be the problem you pointed out.

Comment: @Sparkaward The problem is not radians.